# Mongoose: Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on user model with mongoose. Created some interfaces for using both model methods and statics as in [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics-and-methods.html).

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: 'user' | 'admin';
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  age: number;
  date: Date;
  verified: boolean;
}
interface IUserMethods { // no methods now, interface for future 

}
interface UserModel extends Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods> {
    emailTaken(email: string): Promise<HydratedDocument<IUser, IUserMethods>>;
}
```

Then created the schema, using all interfaces

```
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel, IUserMethods>({...});
```

Then I'm trying to use pre-save hook to hash password, and I get this error:

`Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'`

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next: NextFunction) {
    const user = this;
  
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    }
  
    next();
  });
```

I've tried and `.pre<IUser>` and `.pre<HydratedDocument<IUser>>` and `.pre<HydratedDocument<IUser, IUserMethods>>`, but none has worked.

Comment: Try Like This

import { CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError } from "mongoose";

userSchema.pre("save", function (next: CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError) {
 .......... rest code ............
  next();
});

this is the Correct Next FunctionType for Monoose 
what you have been using is Express Next Function Type

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This This WOrks for me

```
import { CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError } from "mongoose";

userSchema.pre("save", function (next: CallbackWithoutResultAndOptionalError) {
    .............rest code ............
    next();
});
```

**this is the Correct Next FunctionType for Monoose
what you have been using is Express Next Function Type**

please try and let me know if it works

Thanks